# How do I read an XML file with an unbound XML namespace, using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces, xsi

I am trying to read a XML file using JAXB that I don't have control over. I do not have access to the code that creates this file.

I created this simplified, reproducible example. Note the `xsi:type` field that I need to use to determine the correct type to parse to and it the `java` namespace is not bound.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<someObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="java:com.group.module.SomeObject">
    <field>value</field>
</someObject>
```

I created this class:

```
package com.group.module;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Setter
@Getter
public class SomeObject {
    private String field;
}
```

I try to read this file using the following code (JAXB). Note that I could of course pass the type directly to `newInstance()`, but I need to use the `xsi:type` field.

```
File f = new File("file.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance();
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
SomeObject obj = (SomeObject) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(f);
System.out.println(obj.getField());
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
prefix java is not bound to a namespace
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix java is not bound to a namespace
```

How can I parse the XML file into `SomeObject` (or any other type), honoring the `xsi:type` hint, with an unbound `java` namespace?

Comment: Very few tools in the modern XML stack are able to read files that are not namespace-well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `JAXBContext.newInstance();` without any arguments
doesn't make sense according to the [API doc of this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class...-).
You should at least pass the root class:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(SomeObject.class);
```

After changing this in your Java code the XML file is unmarshalled correctly.

[image]